# Why I can't apply colorscheme for GUI vim in Windows?

Tags: gvim, colorscheme, original-vim

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2 (2019 Dec 12, compiled May  2 2021 18:02:30)
MS-Windows 32-bit console version
Included patches: 1-2824
Compiled by mool@tororo
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl                +ex_extra           +multi_lang         -tcl
+arabic             +extra_search       -mzscheme           +termguicolors
+autocmd            -farsi              -netbeans_intg      +terminal
+autochdir          +file_in_path       +num64              -termresponse
+autoservername     +find_in_path       +packages           +textobjects
-balloon_eval       +float              +path_extra         +textprop
+balloon_eval_term  +folding            -perl               -tgetent
-browse             -footer             +persistent_undo    +timers
++builtin_terms     +gettext/dyn        +popupwin           +title
+byte_offset        -hangul_input       -postscript         -toolbar
+channel            +iconv/dyn          +printer            +user_commands
+cindent            +insert_expand      +profile            +vartabs
+clientserver       +ipv6               -python             +vertsplit
+clipboard          +job                -python3            +virtualedit
+cmdline_compl      +jumplist           +quickfix           +visual
+cmdline_hist       +keymap             +reltime            +visualextra
+cmdline_info       +lambda             +rightleft          +viminfo
+comments           +langmap            -ruby               +vreplace
+conceal            +libcall            +scrollbind         +vtp
+cryptv             +linebreak          +signs              +wildignore
+cscope             +lispindent         +smartindent        +wildmenu
+cursorbind         +listcmds           +sound              +windows
+cursorshape        +localmap           +spell              +writebackup
+dialog_con         -lua                +startuptime        -xfontset
+diff               +menu               +statusline         -xim
+digraphs           +mksession          -sun_workshop       -xpm_w32
-dnd                +modify_fname       +syntax             -xterm_save
-ebcdic             +mouse              +tag_binary
+emacs_tags         -mouseshape         -tag_old_static
+eval               +multi_byte_ime/dyn -tag_any_white
   system vimrc file: "$VIM\vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME\_vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "$HOME\vimfiles\vimrc"
 3rd user vimrc file: "$VIM\_vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME\_exrc"
  2nd user exrc file: "$VIM\_exrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME\defaults.vim"
Compilation: cl -c /W3 /GF /nologo  -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_PATHDEF -DWIN32  -DFEAT_CSCOPE -DFEAT_TERMINAL -DFEAT_SOUND  -DFEAT_JOB_CHANNEL -DFEAT_IPV6      -DWINVER=0x0501 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 /source-charset:utf-8 /MP -DHAVE_STDINT_H /Ox /GL -DNDEBUG /arch:IA32 /Zl /MT /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D_CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE -DFEAT_MBYTE_IME -DDYNAMIC_IME -DDYNAMIC_ICONV -DDYNAMIC_GETTEXT -DFEAT_HUGE /Fd.\ObjCi386/ /Zi
Linking: link  /nologo /opt:ref /LTCG:STATUS oldnames.lib kernel32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib gdi32.lib  comdlg32.lib ole32.lib netapi32.lib uuid.lib /machine:i386   libcmt.lib  user32.lib          winmm.lib WSock32.lib Ws2_32.lib  /PDB:vim.pdb -debug
```

Minimal vimrc:

```
call plug#begin('~/vimfiles/plugged')

"Theme for vim
Plug 'dracula/vim',{'as':'dracula'}
Plug 'https://github.com/morhetz/gruvbox.git', {'as':'gruvbox'}
Plug 'https://github.com/tomasr/molokai.git', {'as':'molokai'}
Plug 'https://github.com/rakr/vim-one.git', {'as':'one'}
Plug 'https://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized.git', {'as':'solarized'}
Plug 'https://github.com/sainnhe/edge.git', {'as': 'edge'}
Plug 'https://github.com/sainnhe/everforest.git', {'as': 'everforest'}
Plug 'folke/tokyonight.nvim', { 'branch': 'main' }

"Statusline 
"Plug 'itchyny/lightline.vim'
Plug 'https://github.com/itchyny/vim-gitbranch.git'
Plug 'vim-airline/vim-airline'
Plug 'vim-airline/vim-airline-themes'

"Initialize plugin system
call plug#end()

"Appearance
"Vim in terminal
if !has('gui_running') && has('termguicolors')
    let g:theme = 'dracula'
    set termguicolors
    "let g:lightline = {
    "\ 'colorscheme': 'gruvbox' ,
    "\ }
    colorscheme gruvbox
else
    " set guifont=* "Choose font
    " set guifont?  "Currently font
    set guifont=Cousine_NF:h12:cANSI:qDRAFT
    colorscheme edge
endif
```

Terminal:
[image]

Gui:

[image]

I'm using scoop for downloading vim stable:

```
scoop install vim
```

colorscheme is displayed wrong with scoop. I don't know what happening in here. My minimal vimrc still work when installed with .exe file but using scoop install vim with the same version is broken.

Comment: And your problem is what exactly?

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: I'm at least slightly confused: you have two different colorschemes, so I would expect some difference I suppose. How is the GUI screenshot different from expected? Please [edit]

Comment: You could also double check how the colorscheme behaves with `:set bg`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the issue caused by default `_gvimrc` and `_vimrc` when install vim with scoop. They located at `~\scoop\apps\vim\current\`. Detail [here](https://github.com/ScoopInstaller/Main/issues/3290)